# Self containing logs

Tags: code-golf

## The "problem"

Define a function `log` (or other 3 letter name) which when called will log/print/write (whatever is the default for the language in question) both the instruction (as source) and the first argument. In other words:

```
i=777
j=333
log(i) //outputs: "log(i) 777"
log(i+j+1) //outputs: "log(i+j+1) 1111"
```

For all practical purposes the output `i: 777` would be enough, but in some languages there are very specific reflection libraries for that, and that would be no challenge, so the entire instruction should be outputted.

## Inspiration

The inspiration for this was me and another programmer discussing how irritating it is that often (with bad debuggers), you write things like `console.log("i:", i)`, next we made a (pretty crazy) javascript (node only) solution (it outputs `i: 777` rather than the entire line of source) which was suprisingly long and reminded me of codegolfing and made me wonder how much better other (especially code golfing) languages would fare.

## Bonuses

**-10%**: No file reading (beyond the compiler)

PS. This is my first 'question' here, so feel free to point out any mistakes I made.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! I personally think your question is pretty decent, but it's usually a better idea to run question ideas through [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xi?cb=1) to resolve ambiguities etc before people start working on answers.

Comment: Thx and useful@sandbox, might be good to explain it's use on `help/on-topic` (it's mentioned, but I didn't consider it worth checking the way it was described there).

Comment: @WolleVanillebärLutz: Of course it's not, did you see anyone claim that to be true then?

Comment: The bounty is for TrungDQ (I think his solution is amazing just from a code perspective (better than our node only solution), regardless of length), have to wait 24 hours though before I can award it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## C <s>(40 -10% = 36)</s> (38 -10% = 34.2)

Note that, in C, a `log` function can only be defined for a specific type. Therefore, this `log` "function" takes only `int` arguments.

```
#define log(x)printf("log("#x") %d",x)
```

A more general solution specifies how to print the argument, in addition to the argument itself:

```
#define lg2(f,x)printf("lg2("#x") "f,x)
```

which would be used as e.g. `lg2("%s", "I'm a string");` or `lg2("%f", 3.1415)`.

Comment: I don't think the final brackets around `x` are necessary.

Comment: @ace: I thought they might be needed if the user puts in some odd characters in the argument, but upon reflection I think you're right. I'll remove them.

Answer (score 10):

## Python (65 -10% = 58.5)

This assumes your code is in a file (it produces odd output if invoked in the interactive interpreter):

```
import traceback as t
def log(x):print t.extract_stack()[-2][3],x
```

It has been tested on Python 2.7.6.

Example:

```
def foo():
    x = 1
    log(x)
    for i in xrange(10):
        log(x+i+1)
    return x

log(foo())
```

outputs

```
log(x) 1
log(x+i+1) 2
log(x+i+1) 3
log(x+i+1) 4
log(x+i+1) 5
log(x+i+1) 6
log(x+i+1) 7
log(x+i+1) 8
log(x+i+1) 9
log(x+i+1) 10
log(x+i+1) 11
log(foo()) 1
```

Comment: Nice! Got to say, this is the kind of crazy stuff that interests me as a programmer (negative index on a native function :O ) :P *wonders off to find some docs*

Answer (score 9):

## C++ <s>121</s> <s>71</s> 67 -10% = 60.3

```
#include<iostream>
#define log(x)std::cout<<"log("#x") "<<(x)<<"\n"
```

Used like this:

```
int main() {
    int i = 777;
    int j = 333;
    log(i);
    log(i+j+1);
}
```

Outputs:

```
log(i) 777
log(i+j+1) 1111
```

Comment: You can remove 30 char and make a one-liner if you write it in C instead of C++: `#define log(x)printf("log(%s) %d\n",#x,x)`, but that will only work of integers.

Comment: @ace: then it only works for one type. (Also, this is the solution I proposed, see below)

Comment: @nneonneo I hate it when I forgot to refresh before posting a comment.

Answer (score 5):

## Rebol3 - 31.5 (35 - 10 %)

Here is a simple implementation shortened from @draegtun that works well for numbers:

```
log: func[p][print[{log[}p{]}do p]]
```

Running it outputs:

```
>> log: func[p][print[{log[}p{]}do p]]
>> i: 777
>> j: 333
>> log [i]
log[ 777 ] 777
>> log[i + j + 1]
log[ i + j + 1 ] 1111
```

It can be much more flexible (for displaying the form of non-number types) at **42.3 chars (47 - 10%)**

```
log: func[p][print[{log}mold p mold/only do p]]
```

The output:

```
>> log: func[p] [print[{log}mold p mold/only do p]]
>> log [join "4" 4]
log [join "4" 4] "44"  ;; shows a string
>> log [1 + 2]
log [1 + 2] 3
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (325)

I think this is the `log` function you are looking for:

```
function log(m){L=(new Error()).stack.match(/(at log \([\s\S]+?at .+?:)\d+:\d+/m)[0].split('\n')[1].match(/:\d+:\d+/)[0];N=L.split(':')[1];C=parseInt(L.split(':')[2]);R=new XMLHttpRequest();R.open('GET',location.href,0);R.onload=function(){console.log(R.response.split('\n')[N-1].substr(C-1).split(';')[0]+' = '+m)};R.send()}
```

## Usage

```
<script>
function log(m){L=(new Error()).stack.match(/(at log \([\s\S]+?at .+?:)\d+:\d+/m)[0].split('\n')[1].match(/:\d+:\d+/)[0];N=L.split(':')[1];C=parseInt(L.split(':')[2]);R=new XMLHttpRequest();R.open('GET',location.href,0);R.onload=function(){console.log(R.response.split('\n')[N-1].substr(C-1).split(';')[0]+' = '+m)};R.send()}

function doSomething() {
  var a = 123; log(a); var b = "Hello, I am TrungDQ!"; log(b);
}
doSomething();
var message = "...or just do it out here";
log(message + "!");
</script>
```

### Output

```
log(a) = 123
log(b) = Hello, I am TrungDQ!
log(message + "!") = ...or just do it out here!
```

### Long code

```
<script>
function log(msg) {
  // Get the line number and offset of the line where is function is called
  var lineInfo = (new Error()).stack.match(/(at log \([\s\S]+?at .+?:)\d+:\d+/m)[0].split('\n')[1].match(/:\d+:\d+/)[0];
  var lineNum = lineInfo.split(':')[1];
  var charOffset = parseInt(lineInfo.split(':')[2]);

  // Get the file source
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', window.location.href, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    // Get file source code
    var response = request.responseText;
    // Get the `log` line
    var line = response.split('\n')[lineNum - 1];
    // Get the `log` statement
    var logStatement = line.substr(charOffset - 1).split(';')[0];
    // Print it
    console.log(logStatement + ' = ' + msg);
  };
  request.send();
}

function doSomething() {
  var a = 123; log(a); var b = "Hello, I am TrungDQ!"; log(b);
}
doSomething();
</script>
```

Only works when the script is put inside `<script>` tag which is put in `.html` document because it sends a request to `location.href` to get the source code. JSfiddle, F12 Dev Tool Console, embbed `.js` files won't work, I am trying to make it available everywhere...

Anyway, this question is interesting.

Comment: I'm little skeptical this is cross browsers.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala - (221 - 10%) = 198.9

Yay macros! This is actually exactly the type of stuff they're for.

```
import language.experimental.macros
def log(p:Any)=macro l
def l(c:reflect.macros.Context)(p:c.Expr[Any])={import c.universe._;reify{println("log("+(c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(show(p.tree)))).splice)+") "+p.splice)}}
```

Readable version:

```
import language.experimental.macros
def log(p: Any) = macro l
def l(c: reflect.macros.Context)(p: c.Expr[Any]) = {
  import c.universe._
  val inputString = show(p.tree)
  val inputStringExpr = c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(inputString)))
  reify {
    println("log(" + (inputStringExpr.splice) + ") " + p.splice)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
log(1)
val x = 3
log(x)
val y = 4
log(x+y)
```

Outputs:

```
log(1) 1
log(x) 3
log(x.+(y)) 7
```

Since addition is a method call in Scala, it adds that verbose syntax back in, but it's pretty close! It's also a bit more verbose in a couple of other cases.

Comment: Wow, that's quite interesting to see@the addition of the function. So much cool stuff to learn :D

Answer (score 2):

## bash (21 - 10% = 18.9)

This:

```
alias log=echo;set -v
```

Then use `log` like you would use `echo`:

```
log $((1+1))
```

or

```
A=2
B=3
log $((A+B))
```

This method will do all what is required; as a bonus, some extra information will also be printed, but no explicit rule forbid it.

Answer (score 2):

## BASH

Arguments are not passed using "(...)" in BASH, so I let the output of 'log()' fit that style:

```
$ log(){ echo "$FUNCNAME $@: $(($@))"; }
$ i=333
$ j=777
$ log i
log i: 333
$ log i+j+1
log i+j+1: 1111
```

Comment: `$((...))` can be `$[...]` instead but I did not count the chars, so it doesn't matter up to now.

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 42.3 (47 - 10%)

```
proc log c {puts [dict g [info fr -1] cmd]\ $c}
```

Usage:

```
set i 777
set j 333
log $i  ;#outputs: "log $i 777"
log [expr {$i+$j+1}] ;#outputs: "log [expr {$i+$j+1}] 1111"
```

**Edit**: small improvement

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure

```
(defmacro log[x] `(let [x# ~x] (println "log("'~x")" x#)))
```

Homoiconicity has its benefits!

To use:

```
(def i 777)
(def j 333)
(log i) ;Prints log( i ) 777
(log (+ i j 1)) ;Prints log( (+ i j 1) ) 1111
```

Let's see what's happening with `macroexpand`:

```
(macroexpand '(log (+ i j 1))) 
;; Prints the following: 
(let* [x__1__auto__ (+ i j 1)] (clojure.core/println "log(" (quote (+ i j 1)) ")" x__1__auto__))
```

Comment: If you quote `x`, do you really need to use an intermediate gensym (ie. `x#`)? I think you will only evaluate the expression once (btw, I am no Clojure expert)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 51*0.9=45.9

```
julia> x=4
4
julia> macro log(x) println("log($x) $(log(eval(x)))") end
julia> @log(x)
log(x) 1.3862943611198906
```

Alternatively, but not meeting the rules

```
julia> @show log(x)
log(x) => 1.3862943611198906
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp - 119.7 (133 -10%)

```
(defmacro @(&whole f &rest r)(let((g(gensym)))`(let((,g(multiple-value-list,@r)))(progn(format t"~s~{ ~a~}
"',f,g)(values-list,g)))))
```

- Named `@` because `log` is the standard logarithm function and locked by default (at least on SBCL). Also, `@` is only one character long.
- Acts as a `progn`, taking a variable number of arguments, but prints to standard output. In real applications, I would probably `signal` a condition with  an S-expression instead of printing space-separated output.
- Contrary to the existing Clojure solution, we ultimately returns the value of the logged expression, so that `(@ x)` can be used whenever `x` is used.
- Printing uses `prin1`, which outputs a `read`-able string. This is useful when trying to reproduce logged expressions.
- Handles all possible types (see C answer)
- Takes into account mutliple values
- Does not produce different outputs (see Scala answer)
- Works from a file and from REPL (See Pyhton answer)
- Does not require browser/interpreter trick (Python traceback, Javascript request)

## Sample outputs:

```
CL-USER>(@ (+ 3 2))   ; user input
(@ (+ 3 2)) 5         ; printed output
5                     ; result of expression

CL-USER> (@ (values 3 4))  ; input
(@ (VALUES 3 4)) 3 4       ; logging
3                          ; first value
4                          ; second value

CL-USER>(@ (round 3.4))
(@ (ROUND 3.4)) 3 0.4000001
3                          ; rounded value
0.4000001                  ; delta
```

And finally, if I log the above `defmacro`, I have the ungolfed version:

```
CL-USER> (@ (defmacro @(&whole f &rest r)(let((g(gensym)))`(let((,g(multiple-value-list,@r)))(progn(format t"~s~{ ~a~}
"',f,g)(values-list,g))))))
STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::@ in DEFMACRO
(@
 (DEFMACRO @ (&WHOLE F &REST R)
   (LET ((G (GENSYM)))
     `(LET ((,G (MULTIPLE-VALUE-LIST ,@R)))
        (PROGN
         (FORMAT T ,"~s~{ ~a~}
"
                 ',F ,G)
         (VALUES-LIST ,G)))))) @
@ ; actual result
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 138

You can't redeclare `log` in PHP without using another module (`APD`) so I used `logg` instead, i can resubmit with `log` example if needed. That's minor, but more sinful i guess is that this assume the log function is on a line by itself. I can update my answer as dictated by comments.

```
<?php function logg($v){$b=debug_backtrace()[0];$h=fopen($b['file'],"r");for($i=0;$i<$b['line']&&$l=fgets($h);$i++);echo trim($l)." $v";}
```

example output:

```
for ($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {   
  $j=$i+1;
  $k=$j+1;
  logg($i+$j+$k);
  echo "\n";
}
/*
logg($i+$j+$k); 6
logg($i+$j+$k); 9
logg($i+$j+$k); 12
logg($i+$j+$k); 15
logg($i+$j+$k); 18
logg($i+$j+$k); 21
logg($i+$j+$k); 24
logg($i+$j+$k); 27
logg($i+$j+$k); 30
*/
```